# Confidence interval of slope in linear regression

Tags: regression, confidence-interval

When computing a confidence interval of slope in linear regression, should you use the z- or t-statistic?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://www.weibull.com/DOEWeb/confidence_intervals_in_simple_linear_regression.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're doing linear regression using least squares, you should use base confidence intervals on Student's *t*-distribution.

Comment: ok thanks, stating the statistic was a mistake. I meant z or t table.

Answer (score 5):

**Rule of thumb: Use Student's *t* distribution if you must estimate the variance.**

Since the distribution's variance is estimated (not known), you should use Student's *t* distribution rather than the standard normal distribution (*z*), which requires a known variance.

Although the *t* distribution becomes almost exactly the same as the *z* distribution when the degrees of freedom (think size of the sample) are large, it is (in my experience) quite rare that the *z* distribution is used instead of the *t* distribution in cases like this.

Comment: @whuber: Much obliged. It's quite embarassing that I have been able to contribute little to Cross Validated (compared to other Stack Exchange sites), considering I got my undergrad degree in the university's department of statistics. ;-)

Comment: @Firefeather Be patient. Simple mistakes are no problem; as you've seen, you can edit them ;-).  But sooner or later you'll find some questions where it's obvious you have something valuable and special to contribute.  I look forward to seeing them.

Comment: @whuber: Why, thank you! It may come easier once I start back at school again to get a PhD in Statistics, too.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on assumptions on your disturbances. If they are normal and homoscedastic, then yes use t-statistic. In economic applications though these assumptions rarely hold, so in that case I would suggest using z-statistic with [robust standard errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_standard_errors).

Comment: (+1) It seems to me this advice is complementary rather than countervailing.  After all, using Student's t matters when the degrees of freedom are small and that's usually where you can't detect heteroscedasticity anyway.  So with lots of data you can check assumptions and protect yourself somewhat with robust SEs and, furthermore, you won't really care whether you're using t tables or z tables.